# How can I get perl grep do perform regex expression capturing

Tags: perl

I'm trying to capture a substring using regex capturing with grep by getting the content of (.*) in the code below.

```
            @substring = grep /^test-results(.*)/,@$(array_reference);
```

This is not working....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the `map` function is a better fit for what you want. You're looking for something similar to the following (untested) code:

```
@substrings = map { /^test-results(.*)/ ? $1 : () } @{ $arrayref };
```

Comment: Never use `$1` and friends outside a conditional. Captures are from the last successful match. Better would be `@substrings = map { /^test-results(.*)/ ? $1 : () } @{ $arrayref };`.

Comment: @Greg: Thank you! I had made the assumption that of course everything would match, potentially quite incorrect. Replaced. :)

Answer (score 8):

In list context, a regex match returns a list of what its captures matched, so all you need is:

```
@substrings = map /^test-results(.*)/, @$array;
```